# Calling a function (PHP)

Tags: php

I'm currently writing a key-cipher function to be able to test later through unit testing. I'm very new to PHP and I'm struggling to call a function from the same class. Here is the code:

```
<?php
class Code{

public function keyCipher($code){
    $alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    $alphArr = str_split($alphabet);
    $codeArr = str_split($code);
    $cipher = array();
    $counter = 0;
    foreach($codeArr as &$char1){
        foreach($alphArr as &$char2){
            if($char1 == $char2){
                if(!in_array($char1, $cipher)){
                    $cipher[$counter] = $char1;

                    $counter++;
                }
            }
        }

    }
    foreach($alphArr as &$char1){
        if(!in_array($char1, $cipher)){
            $cipher[$counter] = $char1;

            $counter++;
        }
    }

    return implode($cipher);

}

function cipherSolution($keyword, $code){
    $this -> keyCipher($keyword);

    return $cipher;
}
}
?>
```

I think it has something to do with the -> operator, but I'm not sure how it works.

Wkr

Comment: Do you want to return the value from the call to `keyCipher()`? At the moment, you're discarding it, and trying to return the value of `$cipher`, but you're not doing that properly either.

Comment: Also, what are you intending for the `$code` parameter in `cipherSolution()` which is currently unused?

Comment: The code used to be longer, but I posted a reduced version because I wanted to simplify it as much as I can to try to understand why the code is not working. I've tried "$cipher -> keyCipher($keyword)" as well, which didn't work either. 

It is a discryption function where $code will be the input.

Comment: `$cipher()` isn't in scope inside `cipherSolution()`, it's only available inside `keyCipher()`. Look at my answer - it's almost certainly what you want.

Comment: I get "Using $this when not in object context"

Comment: How are you calling `cipherSolution()`? If you really want this to be object-oriented, try `$code = new Code(); echo $code->cipherSolution("whatever");` However, as things stand, you're not really using any OO features, so I'd probably do away with the class altogether if it were me.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return the value from keyCipher(), try:

```
function cipherSolution($keyword) {
    return $this->keyCipher($keyword);
}
```